# What is the Java equivalent of a Python Dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

I have a Dictionary in Python say

```
{ SERVER1 : [ (list1),(list2),....
  SERVER2 : [ (list2a),(list2b) ] }
```

Is it same can be implemented in Java ? 
I need to check each key if exist then I need to add the list to that key like appending the existing value without overriding
Also need to read the key and value and traverse through each value of list

Kindly assist. Sorry to ask these question as it is my first program in Java

Comment: Yes, use `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: This site has a search function. Use it before posting a new question.

Answer (score 4):

In java, dictionaries are defined with the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface. The common implementations are [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
Map<String,List<String>> servers = new HashMap<>();

servers.put("SERVER1", new ArrayList<String>());
servers.get("SERVER1").add("list1");
servers.get("SERVER1").add("list2");
...
```

Similarly, [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) are common implementations of the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.

Comment: For completeness : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to save each value associated with a key, you need a HashMap that contains ArrayLists for values.  This object should do what you need:

```
public class HashOfLists<K, V> {

    HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public ArrayList<V> get(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        ArrayList<V> existingValues = get(key);
        if (existingValues == null) existingValues = new ArrayList<>();
        existingValues.add(value);
        map.put(key, existingValues);
    }

}
```

To use it you would do something a bit like this:

```
HashOfLists<String, String> servers = new HashOfLists<>();
servers.put("SERVER3", "PROCESS A");
servers.put("SERVER3", "PROCESS B");

//Getting a list containing "PROCESS A" and "PROCESS B"
ArrayList<String> processes = servers.get("SERVER3");
```

Comment: I am reading a file say 
Server1|cmd|blablal
Server2|cmd|blablala
Server1|cmd2|blablal
Server2|cmd4|blabla
Below code returning the last value of each server

Comment: I am reading a file say 
Server1|cmd|blablal
Server2|cmd|blablala
Server1|cmd2|blablal
Server2|cmd4|blabla
Below code returning the last value of each server

Server1|cmd2|blablal
Server2|cmd4|blabla

but I want some thing like 
{Server1 :[(cmd|blablal),(cmd2|blablal)],Server2:[(cmd|blablala),(cmd4|blabla)}

Comment: code is

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
   {
    String[] line_split = line.split("\\|");
    if(line_split.length == 3)
    {

     map.put(line_split[0], (line_split[1] +"|"+ line_split[2]));
    }
   }
   System.out.println(map.keySet());
   for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      String value = entry.getValue();
      System.out.println(key);
      System.out.println(value);
    }